# How to create a white background on an image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys i am trying to create this effect with **bootstrap 3** :

[image]

The black color being a random image and then just a white strip on were I can put my text etc.

So far I have this :

HTML:

```
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="container">
    <h1> Testing </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parallax {
  background-image: url("../img/c.jpg");
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
}
```

However no matter what I change the width to for the container , it does not become smaller just the text inside of it does.

So again I am just looking to have a background image cover the whole browser and then just a white strip coming down but the width to be around 800px; so it leaves gaps on the side to see the image in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of *min-width* and *max-width* on container class. This `ensures that when your browser is resized the sides are still visible` by setting the `width of the container to a relative (%) value`. And the `max-width limits it from extending` beyond that. You can `position the container using transform property` in CSS and make an *animation* for the container to come from top and set its position to the vertical center of the webpage.

As far as the background is concerned, you can set the width or height to 100vw, 100vh or even % as you find suitable. This is just a demonstration.

```css
.parallax {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/300x100");
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -300px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  min-width: 70%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: expand 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {}
  100% {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="container">
    <h1> Testing </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RonTheOld No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="cont">
        hellowold
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parallax {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative; // this is necessary
    background: #000;
}
.cont {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; // for responsive it will take 100% width
    max-width: 800px; // for bigger screen it will be max 800px
    padding: 15px; // just for decoration
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: 0 auto; // absoluted element center purpose
    bottom: 0; // positioning at the bottom as per your image
    left: 0; // absoluted element center purpose
    right: 0;// absoluted element center purpose
    text-align: center; // just for decoration
}
```